# How to fix Assertion Failure Opencv Programming - Visual C++ 2008 Express

Tags: c++, opencv, assertion, visual-c++-2008

I made a windows form based program to load an image using opencv in Visual C++ 2008. 
But, the following code failed to load the image, and got an assertion failure.

```
private: System::Void buttonCitra_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
    {
        //error detected here variable Citra 
        Citra = cv::imread(MarshalString(openFileDialog1->FileName));
        pictureBoxCitra->Image = IplImageToBitmap(&(IplImage) Citra);
        this->Width = pictureBoxCitra->Image->Width+33;
        this->Height = pictureBoxCitra->Image->Height+85;
    }
}
```

When I compile and build it, nothing happened, and the Form appeared properly. But when i chose an image using openFileDialog in my directory file, i got dialog box titled "Microsoft Visual C++ debug library" which contains the assertion failure,as follow :

```
"Debug Assertion Failed!
Program: .....Try.exe
file f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\Self_x86\crt\src\fopen.c
Line 53
Expression: (file!=NULL)"
```

Comment: You might want to tag this [tag:c++-cli] or [tag:c++-cx] or whatever this is instead of just [tag:c++]

Comment: Using C++/CLI just because of GUI is quite desperate thing to do. If the appearance of your application is not that important, stick with MFC instead or use some decent framework otherwise.

Comment: just read the error msg. your file did not exist.

Comment: The issue could be image file is in some format not readable by your program. Try it with a different format image file.